# c# one liner for .ToString() across entire array

Tags: c#, shortcut

I feel stupid for asking, but there must be a one liner that does the equivalent or near equivalent of the code below in c#... so can you tell me what it is?

```
    public static string[] ToStringArray(int[] i)
    {
        if (i==null) return null;
        string[] result = new string[i.Length];
        for (int n= 0; n< result.Length; n++)
            result[n] = i[n].ToString();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about an extension method?

```
public static string[] ToStringArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    return items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: An extension method would work, but why not use the .Net frameworks ".Join" function for this?

Comment: See my comments on your answer. String.Join turns an array of strings into a single string. The original question called for a way to turn an array of ints into an array of strings.

Comment: I missed the whole "int" part of that :)

Comment: I think an extension method would probably look a bit better in the code in the long run then.

Comment: egads, it even works in the watch window:
    (new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5}).ToStringArray()

Answer (score 9):

Using LINQ:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };

string[] strings = ints.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
(from x in i select x.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] x = new int[] {1,2,3};
string[] y = Array.ConvertAll(x, intArg => intArg.ToString());
```